# Path to php executable on a mac with vscode and mamp

Tags: php, mamp, visual-studio-code, mamp-pro

vscode requires path to php set for this parameter:

> "php.validate.executablePath":

so I specified this:

> "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.12/bin/php"

but it isn't recognized.

What is the correct path ?

Comment: Did you try `which php` ?

Comment: /usr/bin/php but I think this is the 5.X php version. The 7 is installed trough mamp and vscode needs 7

Comment: That is the correct settings and I confirmed it works on my machine with VSCode 1.7.2. What happens if you run `$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.12/bin/php --version` from the command line?

Answer (score 38):

I ran into this problem after installing the PHP Intellisense extension in vscode. For Intellisense to work I needed to point vscode at MAMP's version of PHP, not the default OS X version of PHP, but it did not recognise the path I was specifying.

I was able to resolve the issue by specifying the `"php.executablePath"` preference instead of `"php.validate.executablePath"`.

```
"php.executablePath": "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin/php"
```

Here is an [explanation](https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-intellisense/issues/37#issuecomment-269986916) from the author of the package:

> validate has nothing to do with this extension, but is the built-in
> validation of VS Code. I would disable that, because you will get
> duplicate validation. php.executablePath should be set to the path of
> the binary

Comment: `"php.validate.executablePath": "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.2.0", ` worked on me

Comment: for me that installed from bew  is "/opt/homebrew/opt/php/bin/php"

Answer (score 24):

I am using mac i have install [php intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-intellisense)
 that required php version 7 executable path
i have already php 7 installed. Terminal command

`which php`

work for me.

Comment: This command will show you the php installation on your mac, which is different from the php installation in MAMP.

Comment: find MAMP location and inside the installation folder you will find php